# Convert nested objects into an array of objects

Tags: arrays, object

I need to convert a deeply nested object of objects into an array of objects for each level until it has no more "parents"

I am receiving an object like this:

```
   {
    name: '1',
    address: '1',
    parent: {
      name: '2',
      address: '2',
      parent: {
        name: '3',
        address: '3',
        parent: {
          name: '4',
          address: '4',
          parent: {
            name: '5',
            address: '5',
            parent: null,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
[
  { name: '1', address: '1',},
  { name: '2', address: '2',},
  { name: '3', address: '3',},
  { name: '4', address: '4',},
  { name: '5', address: '5',},
]
```

I looked everywhere but I couldn't find a simple and reliable solution.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive option which utilizes the `flat` method to make things simpler:

```js
const data = {
  name: '1',
  address: '1',
  parent: {
    name: '2',
    address: '2',
    parent: {
      name: '3',
      address: '3',
      parent: {
        name: '4',
        address: '4',
        parent: {
          name: '5',
          address: '5',
          parent: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const flattenObject = (acc, curr) => curr.parent ? [...acc, {
  name: curr.name,
  address: curr.address
}, flattenObject(acc, curr.parent)].flat() : [...acc, {
  name: curr.name,
  address: curr.address
}];

const flatData = flattenObject([], data);

console.log(flatData);
```